# Does AWS Charge money for downloading files from S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-cost-explorer

I want to know wheter AWS do charge any money if we download files from S3 bucket? Any suitable references welcome

Answer (score 1):

see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)

AWS charges per request and it charges for data transfer out.